# Strange behavior of data

Tags: avr, c, atmel-studio

I declare global variables to read the sensor MPU9250.

```
typedef struct MPU_data{
    //Accelerometer
    int16_t ax;
    int16_t ay;
    int16_t az;
    //Gyroscope
    int16_t gx;
    int16_t gy;
    int16_t gz;
    //magnetometer
    int16_t mx;
    int16_t my;
    int16_t mz;
}MPU_data;
MPU_data mpu;

int16_t mpu_array[9];
```

In the main loop, I read data

```
while(true)
{
    uint8_t Buf[14];
    I2C_Read(MPU9250_ADDRESS,0x3B,Buf,14);

    // Create 16 bits values from 8 bits data

    // Accelerometer
    int16_t ax=-(Buf[0]<<8 | Buf[1]);
    int16_t ay=-(Buf[2]<<8 | Buf[3]);
    int16_t az=Buf[4]<<8 | Buf[5];

    // Gyroscope
    int16_t gx=-(Buf[8]<<8 | Buf[9]);
    int16_t gy=-(Buf[10]<<8 | Buf[11]);
    int16_t gz=Buf[12]<<8 | Buf[13];

    uint8_t ST1;
    do
    {
        I2C_Read(MAG_ADDRESS,0x02,&ST1,1);
    }
    while (!(ST1&0x01));

    // Read magnetometer data
    uint8_t Mag[7];
    I2C_Read(MAG_ADDRESS,0x03,Mag,7);

    // Create 16 bits values from 8 bits data

    // Magnetometer
    int16_t mx=-(Mag[3]<<8 | Mag[2]); mx += 200;
    int16_t my=-(Mag[1]<<8 | Mag[0]); my -= 70;
    int16_t mz=-(Mag[5]<<8 | Mag[4]); mz -= 700;

    uint8_t mpu_data[48];
    sprintf(mpu_data, "%i, %i, %i; %i, %i, %i; %i, %i, %i;\n", ax,ay,az,gx,gy,gz,mx,my,mz);
    USART_Send_t(mpu_data);
```

I get the normal data

```
3454, -79, -7349; -85, -26, -41; -268, -200, 218;
3450, -76, -7355; -88, -27, -45; -258, -188, 216;
3440, -63, -7364; -84, -26, -43; -259, -195, 219;
3441, -70, -7355; -85, -23, -40; -259, -199, 219;
```

If I write to global variables, I get a different behavior.

```
uint8_t Buf[14];
I2C_Read(MPU9250_ADDRESS,0x3B,Buf,14);

// Create 16 bits values from 8 bits data

// Accelerometer
mpu.ax=-(Buf[0]<<8 | Buf[1]);
mpu.ay=-(Buf[2]<<8 | Buf[3]);
mpu.az=Buf[4]<<8 | Buf[5];

// Gyroscope
mpu.gx=-(Buf[8]<<8 | Buf[9]);
mpu.gy=-(Buf[10]<<8 | Buf[11]);
mpu.gz=Buf[12]<<8 | Buf[13];

uint8_t ST1;
do
{
    I2C_Read(MAG_ADDRESS,0x02,&ST1,1);
}
while (!(ST1&0x01));

// Read magnetometer data
uint8_t Mag[7];
I2C_Read(MAG_ADDRESS,0x03,Mag,7);

// Create 16 bits values from 8 bits data

// Magnetometer
mpu.mx=-(Mag[3]<<8 | Mag[2]); mpu.mx += 200;
mpu.my=-(Mag[1]<<8 | Mag[0]); mpu.my -= 70;
mpu.mz=-(Mag[5]<<8 | Mag[4]); mpu.mz -= 700;

uint8_t mpu_data[48];
sprintf(mpu_data, "%i, %i, %i; %i, %i, %i; %i, %i, %i;\n", mpu.ax,mpu.ay,mpu.az,mpu.gx,mpu.gy,mpu.gz,mpu.mx,mpu.my,mpu.mz);
USART_Send_t(mpu_data);
```

Result

```
3370, -512, 0; 0, -23, 0; -68, -270, -472;
3369, -513, 0; 0, -24, 0; -68, -270, -472;
3365, -510, 0; 0, -24, 0; -68, -270, -472;
3359, -508, 0; 0, -23, 0; -62, -262, -476;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1 (Another strange behavior)**

Like I said, I created a function. In the comments, I noted a place that causes strange behavior.

```
inline void MPU_ReadAll(){
    uint8_t Buf[14];
    I2C_Read(MPU9250_ADDRESS,0x3B,Buf,14);

    // Create 16 bits values from 8 bits data

    // Accelerometer
    mpu_array[0]=-(Buf[0]<<8 | Buf[1]);
    mpu_array[1]=-(Buf[2]<<8 | Buf[3]);
    mpu_array[2]=Buf[4]<<8 | Buf[5];

    // Gyroscope
    mpu_array[3]=-(Buf[8]<<8 | Buf[9]);
    mpu_array[4]=-(Buf[10]<<8 | Buf[11]);
    mpu_array[5]=Buf[12]<<8 | Buf[13];
    uint8_t ST1;
    do
    {
        I2C_Read(MAG_ADDRESS,0x02,&ST1,1);
    }
    while (!(ST1&0x01));

    // Read magnetometer data
    uint8_t Mag[7];
    I2C_Read(MAG_ADDRESS,0x03,Mag,7);

    // Create 16 bits values from 8 bits data

    // Magnetometer
    mpu_array[6]=-(Mag[3]<<8 | Mag[2]); mpu_array[6] += 200;
    mpu_array[7]=-(Mag[1]<<8 | Mag[0]); mpu_array[7] -= 70;
    mpu_array[8]=-(Mag[5]<<8 | Mag[4]); mpu_array[8] -= 700;

    //If I delete the comments here, the program will work fine. 
    //If the data sending is commented out, the program gets stuck in this function.
    //However, I get zeros, as I wrote above.
    /*
    uint8_t mpu_data[48];
    sprintf(mpu_data, "%i, %i, %i; %i, %i, %i; %i, %i, %i;\n", mpu_array[0],mpu_array[1],mpu_array[2],mpu_array[3],mpu_array[4],mpu_array[5],mpu_array[6],mpu_array[7],mpu_array[8]);
    USART_Send_t(mpu_data);
    */
}
```

Comment: First thing you must find out *where exactly* it freezes in your code.

Comment: Is there a reason your MPU_data members are signed, but your local variable versions are unsigned?

Comment: @Anonymous sorry, I completed the post

Comment: @ThePhoton the actual readings are signed, but to construct them from bytes it's necessary to avoid an implicit cast with sign extension.  Often the easiest way to do this is to treat the raw buffer as one of unsigned bytes, construct a 16-bit unsigned value having the same bit pattern as a signed representation, and then treat that as signed.  Conversely, if you start with a signed low-order byte, and aren't very careful in handling that, you'll get the wrong value.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I see what they're doing. But they should probably be doing it the same way in the local-variable case and the global-struct-member case if they want to get the same result. (Never mind that printf doesn't care if the argument is signed or unsigned, it just interprets the bits however you tell it to in the format string).

Comment: @ThePhoton Freeze was due to my inattention. But I do not understand why in the case of global variables I get zeros.

Comment: Are they handling the sign issues differently?  If so I missed that.  Printf actually can have similar issues if signed values shorted than an int are interpreted as ints.

Comment: Probably `I2c_Read()` is putting 0's into the corresponding elements of `Buf`.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, No, but if you ask me "how is this code different from that code" and one uses signed and the other uses unsigned, that's the first thing I'm going to see (and maybe be distracted by so I don't see the actual issue)

Comment: @ThePhoton Maybe. But in the case of local variables, the sensor responds to movements. And if I use global variables, I always get zeros.

Comment: Are these all in the same file?

Comment: @chris-stratton sure

Comment: There's undefined behavior all over the place, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

There's really just 2 possible causes here: either stack overflow or undefined behavior bugs.

Using `sprintf` on a lousy AVR is kind of like letting loose an elephant in a porcelain store. You could have a stack overflow, in which case the problem is the program as whole and no specific line.

Also, be wary of the weird Harvard architecture. When you move variables to file scope, you might paradoxically need to use *more* stack, since the compiler will have to generate all manner of strange "access data" code. Exactly what it does, I don't know. Disassemble and have a look. This is an AVR-only problem that you won't have on less exotic CPUs.

Now as it happens, you also *do* have undefined behavior all over the place.

On a 8 bit MCU such as AVR, code like `my_uint8_t << 8` invokes undefined behavior if the uint8_t contains values larger than `0x7F`, because of implicit integer promotion. You end up with bit shifting data into the sign bits of a 16 bit `int` type which is signed. Boom. GCC has an aggressive optimizer, so it might start making all kinds of strange assumptions. (I just answered a very similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365554/bitwise-operators-whats-the-difference-vs-smthg/366586#366586)).

The sound thing to do is to remove all implicit promotions from the code. There's several possible ways to do this:

```
// messy one-liner
mpu.ax= -(int16_t) ((uint16_t)Buf[0]<<8 | (uint16_t)Buf[1]);
```

or

```
// readable version
uint16_t tmp = (uint16_t)Buf[0]<<8 | (uint16_t)Buf[1];
mpu.ax = -(int16_t)tmp;
```

Comment: And this is one of many reasons why programmers in general and beginners in particular should stop using 8 bit CPUs. It is much harder and requires much more skill to program C for 8-bitters than for 32 bit CPUs.

Comment: @MaratGareev Out of curiousity, did any of the above fixes solve the problem or does it persist?

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not possible to check, because I have already started to redo the entire program. Still, the main problem was in I2C, I'm working incorrectly with this bus.  The symptoms of the hang of the program are the same as here https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/i2c-comm-mpu6050-eventually-keeps-crashingfreezing

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem of such inadequate behavior was the optimization of the compiler. By default it was `Optimize (-O1)`, I changed it to `None (-O0)`. Now the program behaves more predictably.
Also did this

```
volatile int16_t mpu_array[9] = {[0 ... 8] = 0};
```

But still with these changes and the included optimization, the program hangs.

Comment: _"So, the problem of such inadequate behavior was the optimization of the compiler."_ - Possible but unlikely. More likely: your program is subtly wrong (perhaps invoking Undefined Behaviour), and the optimization settings happen to (un)mask the buggy behaviour.

Comment: @marcelm I'll try to analyze the code in detail. But I do not see at close range a difference between these options `int16_t ax = ..` and `int16_t a[9]; a[0] = ...`. The difference in the testimony is present. With the optimization disabled, there is no difference, everything works as it should.

Comment: If you make those globals volatile, you might be able to re-enable the optimization.

Comment: @evildemonic I apologize, I forgot to write that I already did it. But still with these changes and the included optimization, the program hangs.